# Packer template.json: What's the difference between the push "name" and the atlas post-processor's "artifact"?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, vmware, configuration-files, packer

Looking for example at [the packer/atlas tutorial's template.json](https://github.com/gitttt/atlas-packer-vagrant-tutorial/blob/master/template.json), we find at the beginning:

```
  "push": {
          "name": ""
        },
```

and towards the end:

```
"post-processors": [
        [{
            "type": "vagrant",
            "keep_input_artifact": false
        },
        {
            "type": "atlas",
            "only": ["vmware-iso"],
            "artifact": "{{user `atlas_username`}}/{{user `atlas_name`}}",
            "artifact_type": "vagrant.box",
            "metadata": {
                "provider": "vmware_desktop",
                "version": "0.0.1"
            }
        },
```

The official [documentation](https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/introduction.html) says for the push/name configuration option:

> name (string) - Name of the build configuration in the build service.
>   If this doesn't exist, it will be created (by default).

and for the post processor/artifact:

> artifact (string) - The shorthand tag for your artifact that maps to
>   Atlas, i.e hashicorp/foobar for atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/foobar.

First, I do not understand either explanation. Second, shouldn't the actual values always be the same if one uses `packer push`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **push name** is the name that will show up in atlas under "Builds".

The **post-processor artifact** is the vagrant box name. It the name used e.g. via `vagrant box add`. On the atlas website, the boxes are listed when clicking on "Vagrant" in the upper menu.

Note that those names can be different.